# how can I send message to specific user in specific group using asp.net signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I can send message to all group in chat

```
 return context.Clients.Group(sGrp).recieveNotification(message, user, chatid, uuid);
```

I can send message to all group in chat

```
return context.Clients.User(currentuser).seenyou(myname);
```

the problem when i send message to specific user in specific  group
is there is way to do this .

Comment: Same question after 5 years (since technologies change): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200015/target-specific-user-in-group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to send a message to a specific user is by addressing the user by its connection Id. In this case it doesn't matter if he is in a specific group or not. Other than that there's no such thing as a built-in list, that you can iterate on, you need to manage those references by yourself.

Of course, if the desired user is the sender, you can use `Clients.Caller`.